# How to focus into an input box from PrimeNG autocomplete?

Tags: angular, focus, primeng

I want to focus into `inputbox` after **PrimeNg** `autocomplete` `onSelect` event click.

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="itemIdAuto" name="itemIdAuto1" #itemIdAuto1="ngModel" size="15" 
[suggestions]="filteredItemIdAutoSingle" (completeMethod)= "itemIdAutoComplete($event)" field="name" 
(onSelect)="itemOnSelect(itemIdAuto)" placeholder= "Select Item Name" [minLength]="1"></p-autoComplete>

<input type="number" autocomplete="off" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control" name="qty"
[(ngModel)]="model.qty" #qty="ngModel">
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class GridFormComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
}
@ViewChild('aForm') aForm: ElementRef;

itemOnSelect(item) {        
    this.aForm.nativeElement['qty'].focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-mnfqnu)

Hope it will help you,let me know if have any query

thanks

Comment: I need to reverse the process. would you please help me?

Comment: focus on autocomplete from normal inputbox.

Comment: hii look at this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-cnfpag

Comment: focus would be on change of the input , once you will complete changes of input just press enter or do some mouse click it will work as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks. I implement it before but I have a logical mistake. Now it's working.

Comment: Hi. I face another issue about focusing on table row. I want to focus `LastName` when the edit button click. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-crud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: hii I have addded another ans please look into and let me know need any more help...

Comment: @UzzalPrasad let me know if you still face an issue in below answer

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer as per your last comment look at below link and let me know if you found any issue.

one more thing to focus on element i have used jquery so please kindly keep note it.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-crud-ifbeq5)

thanks